# PHP how to trigger user error with trigger_error in an object destructor while the script shuts down?

Tags: php, error-handling, destructor

While implementing some class I've run into a little problem:

If the script ends and [destructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php#example-3147) are called because the script has finished, I wanted to trigger an error occasionally.

I thought the [`trigger_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) function would be of use. However, if `error_reporting(-1)` the triggered error is not send any longer to STDOUT or STDERR - while it is expected to do so (e.g. if not within the __destructor/termination phase of the script, trigger_error works as expected).

If I echo some message out, it will be send to STDOUT (CLI mode).

I now wonder

1. how I can trigger an error in this phase of the application?
2. and/or alternatively how can I detect that currently the script is shutting down because it has successfully ended?

Note: I tested [`connection_status()`](http://www.php.net/connection_status) but it's useless in my case as it's about connection handling only and merely unrelated. I wonder if there is some function that does the same for the scripts execution status (starting, running, exiting).

### Simplified Example Code

This is some very reduced example code to illustrate the issue. Naturally is the error only triggered if it makes sense for the object:

```
<?php
class TriggerTest
{
    public function __destruct()
    {
        trigger_error('You should have missed something.');
    }
}
$obj = new TriggerTest;
exit();
```

The problem is, that `trigger_error()` gets executed but the error does not appear anywhere.

Comment: raising an error in a destructor is not usually considered as a "good" practice.

Comment: @Francis: is it not? How come?

Comment: @chelmertz look at the 2nd note about the destructor : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @Francis: do you mean "Attempting to throw an exception from a destructor [...]"? The question does not mention an exception being thrown, rather a warning/error which does not halt the script.

Comment: @Francis: That note is about throwing an exception. My question is about triggering an error - and if not possible - how to determine if the script is in such a state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Just do it. I had some misconfiguration for the error handler and therefore it did not work. My fault.

However it's still interesting if there is any function or similar [to determine the execution state on shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227611/how-to-determine-that-a-php-script-is-in-termination-phase).

Answer (score 1):

How about if you force the error reporting to be a certain setting, trigger the error and then set the error reporting back to it's normal form?