# How to let the default logging unaffected though using set_exception_handler(...) in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging, php-7, custom-error-handling

I'm writing a simple error handling using [`set_exception_handler(...)`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-exception-handler.php). Everything works fine, but the default exception logging to the `syslog` seems to get disabled, when I use the `set_exception_handler(...)` and log exceptions in my custom file.

For the logging of "non-`Trowable`s" there is a function [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php). If the handler function returns `false`, the normal error handler continues, that means the original PHP error message is stored to the system log. For the exception handler no `return` value is provided.

How to store the original PHP error message to the system log, after the `set_exception_handler(...)`'s callback has been executed?

Comment: There's no native way of doing this as far as I'm aware, but there's a workaround using a custom ExceptionHandler's `__destruct()` method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856173/throwing-exception-within-exception-handler

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Yes, this workaround works. One should may not forgot to set `display_errors` to `0` (in production). Another workaround is [`error_log(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

Comment: Actually even no `__destruct()` is needed -- the `throw` or the `error_log(...)` can simply be executed somewhere at the end of the handler callback.