# Detecting whether PHP is shutting down

Tags: php

How can I detect whether PHP is shutting down? By "shutting down", I mean that a function registered with [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) is currently executing. For example, consider the following code:

```
<?php

function do_something() {
    // How can I detect whether PHP is shutting down.
}

register_shutdown_function('do_something');
do_something();
```

In the above code snippet, I want to be able to detect shutdown from within the `do_something` function.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to detect[...]" ? If `do_something` is fired, that means PHP is already shuting down

Comment: As @Max said, `register_shutdown_function()` is used to call a specific function after the script has completed or exited. Your `do_something()` function will be called when the script has completed.

Comment: Ah sorrry, it looks like I stuffed up the code block. Let me fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine that a PHP script is in termination phase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227611/how-to-determine-that-a-php-script-is-in-termination-phase)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php

// receive true or false for knowing if register_shutdown_function() called this function
function do_something($is_register_shutdown_function = false) {
    // How can I detect whether PHP is shutting down.
    if($is_register_shutdown_function === true){
        file_put_contents('do_something.log', "do_something() - ".time().".".microtime(true)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }

    // do as you please going forward
}

register_shutdown_function('do_something', true); // pass true to the first parameter of do_something()
do_something();
```